# make simple form radio buttons hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form-for

How can I get a hidden radio button using simple-form?

I know that simple-form has a `:as => :hidden` to hide a form field, and a `:as => :radio_buttons` to display a radio button option... but I can't have two `as` options on a field... :)

How can I go about this?

What I've tried:

```
= form.input :type, 
  :as => :radio_buttons,
  :hidden => true, 
  :checked => ...

= form.input :type, 
  :as => [:radio_buttons, :hidden]
  :checked => ...

= form.input :type, 
  :as => :radio_buttons,
  :as => :hidden,
  :checked => ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"hidden" is a different form of input altogether - it's the same as [`hidden_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-hidden_field). If you just want to hide a radio from the user (maybe you want to show it again later) you can use "display: none" in the html for the wrapper.

```
= form.input :type
  as: radio_buttons
  wrapper_html: { style: "display: none" }
```

If the input should never be displayed to the user then I'd just leave it out of the page altogether. You're never going to be able to selected it after all.